# How to use this path in the textmate snippets?

Tags: textmate, code-snippets

I would like to have a string that is $TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY-$TM_FILEPATH.....
the `$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY` is

```
/Users/me/Desktop/project/application/app_name
```

and `$TM_FILEPATH` is `/Users/me/Desktop/project/application/app_name/application/models/user_model.php`

The result I want:

```
application/models/user_model.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in raw snippet syntax, but you can create snippets on the fly using the Commands.

So, to do what you want you must create «New Command», then make a snippet you want in, for example, ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print ENV['TM_FILEPATH'].gsub(/^#{ENV['TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY']}\//,'')
```

then in `Input` set `none` and in `Output` set `Insert as Snippet`.

Actually, using any programming language TextMate understand you can create a lot of powerful snippets on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

`${TM_FILEPATH/$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY\//}`

See Section 7.7 "Snippets/Transformations" in the TextMate Help for details.

Comment: Sad, but this syntax works only for the mirrored tabstops, so you can't use this for default and only placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue myself.  Here's the snippet I used:

```
FILEPATH=${TM_FILEPATH/#$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY\//}
echo -n "$FILEPATH"
```

The surrounding backticks execute the shell code when Textmate inserts the snippet.